# After porting from Qt5.15.2 to Qt6.5 QML Material style doesn't work on Win64

Tags: windows, qt, qml

Currently i'm porting a c++/qt(qml) application from qt 5.15.2 to 6.5.
The application is using Material style via runtime selection of a style (qtquickcontrols2.conf), so in a concrete file i'm using `import QtQuick.Controls`.
Deploying of the application is done via windeployqt.
It's weird for my PC the application is working correctly, but on the another PC of my customer it show the empty screen and here is the log

```
qrc:/CustomTextField.qml:4 ??? �TextField� ??????????
qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls/Material/TextField.qml:36 ??? �CursorDelegate� ??????????
qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls/Material/impl/CursorDelegate.qml:14 Connections ?? ???????? ?????
```

i checked if a Material plugin is deployed - yes it is.
Everything worked just fine on Qt5.15.2...
Please help...

Comment: windeployqt isn't bullet proof, sometimes you need to hand review the deployment folders

Comment: I did, Material qml files are there, as well as material plugin...

Comment: Can you post your CMakeLists.txt file (if you are using CMake). Maybe there is something we can see in there...

Comment: The process we follow is we deploy the entire bin, lib, and qml folders - which, is overkill, but is guaranteed to work. Then, through explorative trial and error, remove files until we determine the missing dependency.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot from this description. The best you are going to get without sharing a minimal compilable example is a few comments. *windeployqt* could be using paths defined in environment variables that point to Qt 5.15.x and copying those files over when you try to create a deployment package for the Qt 6 application. Maybe uninstalling Qt 5.15.x helps!